# What is the Regex to capture only digits from some data

Tags: javascript, regex, notepad++, regedit

I have some thing log like this

```
[2/16/18 3:07:24:515 GMT] 0000026b LoggerScripta I   ******Print all instances******10075
[2/16/18 3:07:24:516 GMT] 0000026b LoggerScripta I   ******Print all instances******10078
[2/16/18 3:07:24:516 GMT] 0000026b LoggerScripta I   ******Print all instances******10080
```

Around 300 lines..But I need only those digits(10075) in each line and rest shoulbe removed.Is there any regex that can help easily to get those,

I m using Notepad++

Any help would be very useful since will save our day

Comment: try this `/\d+$/g`

Comment: It didnt worked.Should I replace above pattern with blank?

Comment: how those log is represented in javascript 
. array of string  or just one single string

Comment: @PunithJain Just a single string in each line

Comment: Isn't your string is as shown in the question? if it is multiline use `/\d+$/gm`

Comment: or else any way to rempve the whole data between
[2/16/18 3:07:24:398 GMT] ?

Comment: Use `(\d+)$|(?s:.)` and replace with `(?1$1\n:)`

Comment: you can get your capturing group doing (\d+[$|\n]) then \1. I don't know how to do substitutions with javascript but this should help you ... hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go ahead and assume that each of those lines is a string and each string is an element in an array. If that assumption holds true, then here is the code. Otherwise, please update with how that data is stored in JavaScript and I will rewrite my answer:

```js
// If your logs are an array of strings...
var logs = [
  '[2/16/18 3:07:24:515 GMT] 0000026b LoggerScripta I ******Print all instances******10075',
  '[2/16/18 3:07:24:516 GMT] 0000026b LoggerScripta I ******Print all instances******10078',
  '[2/16/18 3:07:24:516 GMT] 0000026b LoggerScripta I ******Print all instances******10080'
];

var numbersFromArray = logs.map((val) => {
  return val.split('***')
    .reverse()[0];
});

console.log(numbersFromArray);

// If your logs are a single string...
var logs = '[2/16/18 3:07:24:515 GMT] 0000026b LoggerScripta I ******Print all instances******10075 [2/16/18 3:07:24:516 GMT] 0000026b LoggerScripta I ******Print all instances******10078 [2/16/18 3:07:24:516 GMT] 0000026b LoggerScripta I ******Print all instances******10080';

var numbersFromString = logs.split('[')
  .map((val) => {
    return val.split('***')
      .reverse()[0]
      .trim();
  })
  .filter((val) => val !== '');

console.log(numbersFromString)
```

Comment: How can we easily make the whole thing as string i mean add those ' ',
for all

Comment: If your log file is one giant string, then I can add to my code to show that example as well.

Comment: It would be grateful

Comment: @hammy => I added the functionality if you were dealing with one giant string, regardless of whether it is all a single line or multiple lines. The function won't care how many lines it contains.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using notepad++ and you want to remove everything but the last digits before the newline character, it should be sufficient to do a find/replace with regex enabled

Find: `(.*\*)(\d+(\r\n)?)`

Replace (regex): `\2`

What it does:

The first capture group looks for anything (greedy) that ends with an asterisk.

The second capture group looks for a group of digits plus newline if it's there (it might not be for the last log statement).

The replace will leave you only with the second capture group for each line.

Answer (score 0):

With Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?(\d+)$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginning of line
.+?     : 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
(       : start group 1
  \d+   : 1 or more digits
)       : end group
$       : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
10075
10078
10080
```